# Do Statement that isn't working correctly

Tags: java

I can't figure out why the second do statement is not repeating.  It appears to be exiting regardless of the while statement being true or false.  I feel like it's something small I'm missing, but any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
    public void ShellSort()
{
    int gap = size/2;
    do
    {
        boolean swapflag = true;
        do
        {
            swapflag = false;
            for(int s = 0; s < (size-gap); s++)
                if (arr[s] > arr[s + gap])
                    {
                        int temp = arr[s];
                        arr[s] = arr[s + gap];
                        arr[s + gap] = temp;
                        swapflag = true;
                    }
        } while (swapflag = true);
        gap = gap/2;
    } while (gap >= 0);
}
```

Comment: `while (swapflag)`

Answer (score 1):

replace below line

```
while (swapflag = true); //this say that you are always setting swapflag to true
```

with

```
while (swapflag);// check condition true or false
```

Answer (score 1):

The while statement in your code is  `while (swapflag = true);`
Thus your swap flag gets set to true. The inner do-while loop never terminates.
This statement should be either:

```
while(swapflag==true)
```

or `while (swapflag)`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have used an assignment operator = in first while statement instead of relational operator ==.
The = assignment operator  sets your swapflag to true instead  of comparing. 
Change it with
while(swapflag==true)
== is relational operator which will check if swapflag is true
or while (swapflag)